# Forloop problem in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm using JSTL to loop over a list of shop objects. It looks like the following:

```
    <c:forEach items="${shops}" var="shop"> 
       <div class="odd">
            <li class="table-shop">${shop.name}</li>
       </div> 
    </c:forEach>
```

Now I want to be able to get the shop's position in the list. For example if it's the first shop, I'd like to print out `0` next to the name of the shop.

What's the best way I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `varStatus`, e.g.:

```
<c:forEach items="${shops}" var="shop" varStatus="loop"> 
   <div class="odd">
        <li class="table-shop">${loop.index} ${shop.name}</li>
   </div> 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:forEach items="${shops}" var="shop" varStatus="status"> 
       <div class="odd">
            ${status.count}
            <li class="table-shop">${shop.name}</li>

       </div> 
    </c:forEach>
```